# What are required topics I need to learn before tackling Jacobian Conjecture?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, jacobian-conjecture

Dear MathOverFlow advisers,

I am very interested in learning about the Jacobian Conjecture, which I learned of its existence while reading articles about the machine learning's inverse learning functions from polynomial estimation.  I am very interested in reading about it, but I am not sure which topics I need to learn well and which resources cover the conjecture.  Currently, I am reading Mumford and EGA, but I know they are not enough to tackle the problem.

Could you help me out with an introduction to J.C.?  Also, is there an official website that maintains the open problems in algebraic geometry?

Comment: I would say that the Jacobian Conjecture is interesting *exactly* because nobody knows what one has to learn before an attempt to get at it seriously.